# Python - How can I make a function parameter global?

Tags: python, python-3.x, global

For example, I want to call a function LSE(n).
And once I call LSE(5), I want n to be a callable by other functions as 5. I tried nesting the other functions accessing n inside LSE, but it could not access n too.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9242812/python-function-parameter-as-a-global-variable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python function parameter as a global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9242812/python-function-parameter-as-a-global-variable)

Comment: While the question is similar, the accepted answer for above question does not help me. I want to let the user call a single function with several parameters, and several other functions will be called by the first function to do the computation needed with the parameters, before returning a single value to the user. I am unable to think of a way the return method can do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Between functions this can be achieved with the `global` keyword. This approach is usually frowned upon.

```
n = 0
def LSE(value):
    global n
    n = value

def second_func():
   global n
   print(n)
```

trying this out:

```
>>> LSE(5)
>>> second_func()
5
```

If you want to share values between functions, may I suggest encapsulating them in a class?

Comment: Is there anyways to do the global thing without changing the name? I.e. I want to take my parameter make it a global variable retaining the same name (as opposed to here where value and n are named differently)

Comment: maybe. Why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 0):

"Is there anyways to do the global thing without changing the name? I.e. I want to take my parameter make it a global variable retaining the same name (as opposed to here where value and n are named differently)"

from: [How to get the original variable name of variable passed to a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749796/how-to-get-the-original-variable-name-of-variable-passed-to-a-function)

"You can't. It's evaluated before being passed to the function. All you can do is pass it as a string."

What is doable is you can make your code always use a specific variable name, and within your function, declare it a global variable. That way you wouldnt even need to pass it as a parameter, but it would get affected every time you used the function; example:

```
def test_function ():

    global N

    N = N + 1

    print (N)

N = 5

test_function()
test_function()
test_function()
```

> > > 6
> > >       7
> > >       8

Comment: I see, but the above method does not allow me to take in a parameter with name N still, but thanks for the clarification!